# Set negative learning rate in torch.optim. One way fails while another works, why?

Tags: python, machine-learning, pytorch

I want to define an optimizer in pytorch for my code.

The code needs to have a negative learning rate for a special alogrithm.

When I write code like this:

```py
import torch

class Net(torch.nn.Module):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.linear1 = torch.nn.Linear(3, 2)

    def forward(self, x):
        return self.linear1(x)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    net = Net()
    main_model_params = [{
        "params": [p for _, p in net.named_parameters()],
        "weight_decay": 0.0,
    }]
    optimizer = torch.optim.AdamW(
                main_model_params,
                lr = -0.1
            )
    print(optimizer)
```

Then an error will happens:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File ".\experiment\optim_test.py", line 18, in <module>
    optimizer = torch.optim.AdamW(
  File "C:\ProgramData\Miniconda3\lib\site-packages\torch\optim\adamw.py", line 70, in __init__
    raise ValueError("Invalid learning rate: {}".format(lr))
ValueError: Invalid learning rate: -0.1
```

But when I change a method to write the code:

```py
import torch
import torch.nn

class Net(torch.nn.Module):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.linear1 = torch.nn.Linear(3, 2)

    def forward(self, x):
        return self.linear1(x)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    net = Net()
    main_model_params = [{
        "params": [p for _, p in net.named_parameters()],
        "weight_decay": 0.0,
        "lr": -0.1
    }]
    optimizer = torch.optim.AdamW(
                main_model_params,
            )
    print(optimizer)
```

It can be executed rightly:

```
AdamW (
Parameter Group 0
    amsgrad: False
    betas: (0.9, 0.999)
    eps: 1e-08
    lr: -0.1
    maximize: False
    weight_decay: 0.0
)
```

Who can tell me why?

Answer (score 0):

This seems to be an implementation loophole, since the sanity check to make sure the learning is not negative is present in the initializer of the [`optim.AdamW`](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/generated/torch.optim.AdamW.html?highlight=adamw#torch.optim.AdamW) class [here](https://github.com/pytorch/pytorch/blob/master/torch/optim/adamw.py#L79-L80) but is not present when looping over the different parameter group parameters once in the parent [`Optimizer`](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/optim.html#torch.optim.Optimizer) class [here](https://github.com/pytorch/pytorch/blob/c6c03669992826dd5110e78554708a557c5da712/torch/optim/optimizer.py#L284). This is the reason why you can provide a negative learning rate when defined inside the group's parameter.